# Change component's state on success from remote jquery ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, flux

I can do this with axios, as far it returns `promise` which I can resolve later. Example with axios:

in `api.js` file I have this:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
    listUsers() {
        return axios.get(`api/users`);
    },

    addUser(data) {
        return axios.post(`api/adduser`, data);
    }
}
```

And then I use this `api object` in my later code and it works good:

file `usersActions.js`:

```
import api from '../api';

const UsersActions = {
...
    loadUsers() {
         api.listUsers()
        .then(({ data }) =>
            AppDispatcher.dispatch({
                type: Constants.LOAD_USERS_SUCCESS,
                users: data
            })
        )
        ...
    }
};
```

But can I do something like this with `jquery.ajax`?

Comment: Why would you want to? If you don't like Axios, why not just use a simple `fetch`.

Comment: Not sure what version of jQuery you are using but `$.ajax` returns a promise like so you can do: `var something = $.ajax({type:"GET"});something.then(x=>console.log(x))` Since version 2 you should be ok. Not sure why you would want to add jQuery to a react application but if you need to then go for it. What particular problem or error do have using `$.ajax`? and what version of jQuery are you using?